# Looping Parsed JSON creates double Apply to Each

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, json, loop

I've got a list with ~4500 Elements.

With **Select** I took the output of the **Get Elements**.
[image]

Now I parsed the Select-output with the **Parse JSON**
[image]

Now I want to loop through the output and put Name, Email and Ressort for each entry together into a string variable formatted as HTML.
[image]
The HTML should then be put in an email (for testing) and send to me.
[image]

***Now here's my problem:***

When adding a condition, that only entries with *Array_Pilotteilnehmer is equal false* and put the **Compose String** in the Yes part, it generates a *Apply to Each* loop within the first loop.
[image]

Now it would loop 4500 * 4500 times my list which should be really slow.
I want to avoid looping the SharePoint element itself because it's much slower than working with variables/JSON.

How can I solve this/make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the 2nd [Apply to each] action, we can use [Current item] and its properties in expressions like `items('Apply_to_each')?['ID']`. You may not need [Parse JSON] action here to retrieve the properties from [Select] action's output. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm!
Too bad we have to use expressions to access the items from **Select** but this can be made easier when they are put into variables for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, if you have select the required elements, I will say directly use the `create a html table` action. No need to add the condition to get the needed records. Using `Get Items` action, you can set a query to filter all the entries and get the ones you want. Then use the `select` action to choose needed columns. And finally use the action `create a html table.`

An example here:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-and-format-html-table-using-microsoft-flow-and-sharepoint-online/

Filter and how to use get items:https://tahoeninjas.blog/2019/07/03/using-the-sharepoint-getitems-action-in-flow/

Comment: My problem is not the condition of *Pilotteilnehmer* , I can set that in the Get Elements as well. Even if I remove that condition it generates a double **Apply to Each** block and I can't get rid of it.

I tried using the Array as Loop and get the values via **variables('arUserliste').Array_Email** but this produces only errors.

Atm I see no way to loop through the array and extract every value per entry. :(